# Долгий поиск match/against из php

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Проблема такая: один и тот же SQL запрос из PHP может идти например 45 секунд (логируется все точно - это только время запроса, а не загрузки всей страницы), а просто из консоли 5 секунд.

Вот пример такого запроса:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `articles_index` 
WHERE (`contest_id`='2019') AND (match (name, authors, text) against ('Электронная коммерция')) 
ORDER BY match (name, `authors`, text) against ('Электронная коммерция') DESC 
LIMIT 50;
```

А вот DDL таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `articles_index` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `contest_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `authors` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk-articles_index-contest_id` (`contest_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `search` (`name`,`authors`,`text`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk-articles_index-contest_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contest_id`) REFERENCES `contests` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk-articles_index-id` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Из PHP используется Yii2. Записей в таблице около 57к.

Comment: *Из PHP используется Yii2.* И текст запроса, который построил Уй, в точности соответствует показанному? и перед ним больше ничего на сервер не шлётся? *логируется все точно - это только время запроса, а не загрузки всей страницы* Где? Как? Как учитывается время сетевого трансфера? Согласен ли с этими данными General Log?

Comment: @Akina в Yii2 есть дебаг-панель которая сама все логирует. Я просто читаю логи. Там указано время всех запросов которые были на странице. Других тяжелых запросов там нет. Это именно страница поиска статей.

Comment: так а запросы совпадают?

Comment: @n.osennij ну естественно. Я просто скопировал из логов запрос и запустил

Comment: *Я просто читаю логи.* Угу. Вот только выводы из них делаете неверные - потому что ограничиваетесь логами только одной стороны. *Я просто скопировал из логов запрос* Из логов Уя? ну-ну... А MySQL русским по белому говорит "Я выполню этот запрос за 5 секунд"... так вот - надо не удивляться, а искать, какая сволочь съела остальные 40 секунд. И я очень сомневаюсь, что это MySQL...

Comment: @Akina вы не иронизируйте, а скажите какие еще логи вы хотите видеть. Я вам скопирую.

Comment: Я уже сказал - General Log от MySQL-сервера. Покажите, что получил MySQL (а не что ему хотел отправить Уй), и сколько времени MySQL потратил на работу. И совместите это с логом самого Уя - и всё со штампами времени, и чтобы с долями секунды. дабы видно было, кто, когда, чего и сколько (смешать и отсортировать).

Comment: @Akina сейчас я разобрался как включить этот general log, но я вижу что он не логирует время запросов... Точнее он записывает только время начала и сам запрос, но не длительность.

Comment: @Akina а, вот. `slow_query_log` пишет и длительность тоже: # Query_time: 98.182130  Lock_time: 0.000314 Rows_sent: 14  Rows_examined: 13162
SELECT `id` FROM `articles_index` WHERE (`contest_id`='2019') AND (match (name, authors, text) against ('Определение конкурентоспособности товара')) ORDER BY match (name, `authors`, text) against ('Определение конкурентоспособности товара') DESC LIMIT 50;

Comment: Включите профилирование ([SHOW PROFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html) или [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/profiling-table.html))и снимите профиль запроса. Ну не бывает так, чтобы выполнение запроса зависело от того, откуда он поступает... Да, изменения сессионных настроек (запросы соединения перед собственно селектом) посмотрел?

Comment: @Akina сейчас что-то случилось после включения логирования и из консоли также долго стал запрос длиться. Вот сейчас вообще ужас - 227 секунд... Вот результаты профилирования: http://skrinshoter.ru/i/271218/0H8QTO3W.png

Comment: Ну то есть всё время съедает `sending data`. Это - время на считывание данных (а вовсе не отправка результата, как думают многие - [пруф от Heikki Tuuri](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37411#c172475)). Думаю, надо повнимательнее присмотреться к дисковой подсистеме сервера...

Comment: @Akina есть какие-то рекомендации? Там XFS сейчас и CentOS 7

Comment: Дополнительно - попробуйте создать индекс (contest_id, id) вместо индекса по (contest_id)... ну или сперва в дополнение к нему (ну и посмотрите, изменится ли EXPLAIN, само собой). А по поводу оптимизации дисковой подсистемы сервера и тюнинга настроек MySQL-сервера ничего сказать не могу, ибо, если честно, не спец.

Comment: @Akina зачем? По id ничего не ищется - он только выбирается. Я вот еще попробовал убрать поле text - без него стало искать почти мгновенно. Что вообщем-то логично - там очень много данных (текст статьи). Может пока так и оставлю временно...

Comment: *зачем? По id ничего не ищется - он только выбирается* Вот именно. Без учёта match-against это получится покрывающий индекс. А поскольку полнотекст самостоятелен, то есть шанс получить index merge без обращения к таблице.